# C# check for duplicate key and summarize value

Tags: c#

I am iterating through a datatable, and depending on same values I am saving them in a dictionary. But even if the values already exist they get double inserted in the dictionary. Therefore I need to check if the key exist already in the dictionary and summarize its value (old value + new value).

```
 Dictionary myDictionary = new Dictionary<string,int>();
 foreach(var row in myDataTable)
 {
      var currentRow = myDataTable.Rows[loopRowIndex];
      bool existProjNr = KMProductTable.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<int>("ProjNr").Equals(currentRow.ItemArray[0])).Count() > 0;
      bool existTaskNr = KMProductTable.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<decimal>("TaskNr").Equals(currentRow.ItemArray[1])).Count() > 0;
      bool existEmp = KMProductTable.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<string>("EmpR").Equals(currentRow.ItemArray[2].ToString())).Count() > 0;

    if(existProjNr && existTaskNr && existEmp)
    {
       myDictionary.Add($"{currentRow.ItemArray[0].ToString()}_{currentRow.ItemArray[1].ToString()}_{currentRow.ItemArray[2].ToString()}", Convert.ToInt32(currentRow.ItemArray[3]))
    }
}
```

So, if the trio (`ProjNr`, `TaskNr` and `Emp`) exist in the dictionary, I want to add the new value to the old value (old + new).
Otherwise, I want to add that new key to the dictionary (but this is not part of the question).

Comment: Dictionary class has the method _ContainsKey_

Comment: You might also be able to use `GroupBy` on your rows, add the resulting values together once they've been grouped by the key, then convert the result to  a dictionary.

Comment: It is impossible to put two items into a dictionary with the same key.  So how are they getting double inserted?

Comment: @mikebridge can you please show with an example with GroupBy

Comment: @jdweng you are right, they don't and can't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your if statement is checking if they exist and if they do, add them so that is why you are getting multiple values in the dictionary.

As for checking if the item exists, you can use the [`ContainsKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.containskey?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Collections_Generic_Dictionary_2_ContainsKey__0_) method.

For example:

```cs
if (!myDictionary.ContainsKey("ProjNr"))
{
    // ProjNr does not exist, add it
    myDictionary.Add(...);
}
else
{
    // ProjNr exists, increment it
}
```

Comment: and how to do the addition of the actual value with the new value?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Can you be more specific please?

Comment: inside the else (where the ProjNr exist, how to increment the actual value in the dictionary with the new value?